# Number of levels in recursion tree.

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

[image]

See in the picture that the number of levels is clearly $1+\log_{4/3} n$.
so,the total cost should be $cn(1+\log_{4/3} n)$
However in clrs and Khan Academy article of Cormen they are doing $cn\log_{4/3} n$,and saying levels are $\log_{4/3} n$.

Can anyone make me understand this? Got struck since many days.

Comment: Clearly, neither of the numbers can be correct. If $n$ is an integer, then $\log_{4/3}n$ and $1+\log_{4/3}n$ are not integers, hence cannot equal the number of levels.

Comment: For large $n$ the two numbers are pretty much the same: you use a recursion tree to solve some a recursion relation which described the complexity of some algorithm. For such problems we are usually only interested in how fast the solution grows, i.e. if it's $\mathcal{O}(n)$ or $\mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$ etc. Haven't checked your derivation, but both the answers you give have the same complexity.

Comment: @Winther Can you kindly check it please.In all other cases it is given(1+logn),only in this case it is written log n

Comment: Ok, but to me there is no difference between $\log(n)$ and $1+\log(n)$. These kinds of problems are always approximate. For one thing you are not counting the number of levels, you are estimating it (as was pointed out above $\log(n)$ is not an integer).